# Make UWP Color Picker Smaller or Larger

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[UWP Color Picker Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/color-picker)

There doesn't seem to be a way out of the box to adjust the size of the Color Picker in UWP. Setting Width as seen in the example below doesnt seem to do anything. Setting Height just cuts off the rest of the color picker that is below the specified height.

Am I missing something? Has someone else already come up with a workaround? This seems like it should be something that's out of the box.

```
<ColorPicker x:Name="myColorPicker"
         ColorSpectrumShape=”Ring”
         IsColorPreviewVisible="False"
         IsColorChannelTextInputVisible="False"
         IsHexInputVisible="False"
         Width="50"
         Height="50"
         />
```

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out. All I had to do was wrap the ColorPicker in a ViewBox element.

```
<Viewbox Margin="5" MaxWidth="150" Stretch="Fill">
    <ColorPicker x:Name="myColorPicker"
     ColorSpectrumShape=”Ring”
     IsColorPreviewVisible="False"
     IsColorChannelTextInputVisible="False"
     IsHexInputVisible="False"
     />
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: No problem @luigi! You'd think the control would have size properties... Oh well.

Comment: Yeah, not only you can't change the width or height of the control. It doesn't even have a Header property. Anyways, a TextBlock and Viewbox inside a StackPanel solves the issue.